# Problem getting Barba.js to work after it been working fine

Tags: javascript, wordpress, barbajs

I have an issue with site I have taken over. It was all working fine and dandy until one day without any interference Barba.js stopped working, and spat out the error.

'Error: [@barba/core] No Barba wrapper found'

Site: https://soulwood.studiovs.co.uk

Now I haven't used Barba.js but it seems straightforward and the site was working fine. The error seems to say the wrapper (as laid out in the [documentation](https://barba.js.org/docs/getstarted/markup/)) is missing but I have checked and it's not!

Any ideas / directions I could take a look into from an experience Barba.js user(s)?

I'm hosted on nGoDaddy :( Site is Wordpress

Comment: Make sure that your wrapper is not missing. It looks like ```<body class="page" data-barba="wrapper">..</body>``` or```<div id="barba-wrapper">..</div>```

Comment: @KeyboardCorporation Thanks for helping but yes, I have checked it has the required wrapper. The odd thing is that the site has been working fine for weeks, just suddenly Barba.js stopped working and nothing has been changed code wise.

Comment: Maybe its executed before the page loads so cant find your element ?

Comment: Maybe there's a new one and the version of your Barba.js is old. Try to update it.